# Есть ли какие-то общедоступные сервисы/сайты/программы/библиотеки, позволяющие описать картинку словами?

Tags: нейронные-сети, поиск-библиотек, поиск-программ

У того же гугла есть нейросеть, которая по фото может в виде фразы описать, что на нём происходит.

Вопрос: есть ли какието общедоступные сервисы/сайты/программы/библиотеки которые позволяют это делать?

Comment: Ну вообще, если говорить о питоне, то есть прекрасная библиотека opencv. С ее помощью можно сделать что-то, начиная от распознавания цвета, до распознавания лиц.

Comment: с таким же успехом можно говорить о любом языке где удосужились сделать обертку над opencv, исходный код которой на c++

Comment: Сам не пользовался, но вот сервис https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/computervision/describeimage/describeimage, кто как считает? Только русского языка нет, если это важно...

Comment: @mrEvgenX, о, это прям то, что нужно, только минус, что нужна подписка, ну а так прекрасно, спасибо

Answer (score 3):

У Гугла есть сервис [Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision), который позволяет, в том числе, найти всевозможные объекты на фото, подсказать подходящий запрос, [и тому подобное](https://cloud.google.com/vision/pricing). Там же можно [проверить работу, загрузив своё фото.](https://www.gstatic.com/cloud-site-ux/vision/vision.min.html)

Первые 1000 запросов каждый месяц - бесплатные. Дальше - $1.5 за каждую 1000.

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот у Microsoft есть что-то подобное : https://sketch2code.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Данный сервис создан для преобразования картинки в html код, но не как не для описания того, что на картинке происходит

Comment: Простите, мне показалось это интересным

Comment: Я не спорю, сайт классный, но не то что я ищю

Answer (score 0):

Уже многое сказали, но вот еще один сервис для анализа фото и видео при помощи машинного обучения от Amazon - [Amazon Rekognition](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/rekognition/)

А вот прайс-лист для [Computer Vision API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/computer-vision/) от Microsoft

Ну а если просто нужно найти объекты на фото, загрузите их в [Google Photo](https://photos.google.com/) и в поле поиска впишите необходимый объект)

Answer (score 0):

Внезапно, Instagram.

Явно нигде не указано, но если покопаться в коде страницы с изображениями, то можно найти ключевые слова с описанием картинки.

Скорее всего сделано для людей с ограниченными возможностями.

Comment: Это какой человек с ограниченным возможностями полезет в код страницы чтобы понять что на изображении?

Comment: Человек может и не полезет, но от скринридера не спрячешься.